# Cannot find where this color is declared at

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have inherited a wordpress site using a theme. There is a background color on hover in the portfolio section of the site that we want changed. I cannot find where this color is declared at so I can change it. I thought it was an element called gallerySelectorList but nothing I did changed the color. The demo site of this theme is here :  http://demo.pixelentity.com/?surreal

If anyone can help me that would be great I am losing my mind trying to track this thing down and change it. I posted on the creator of the theme's forum but got no where.

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools, they are extremely useful for front end development, usually activated by hitting `F12` in the browser

Comment: Inspect the css using firebug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the Chrome Developer Tools you can invoke the `:hover` state of any element. In this case, you want to do so for the `li` wrapping the link. When do we do this, we see the color is set here:

```css
.gallerySelectorList li:hover {
    background: #83103e;
}
```

[image]

This code is located within your HTML file:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was using Firebug inspector and couldn't see that css declaration. Maybe I'll switch to Chrome :)

Comment: @SamCromer Don't *switch* to anything. Use all of the tools available to you. In this particular instance, Chrome is a good tool.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's not actually a hover, but more so being faded in background color. Found then pink color in the class thumbTextWrap.

.thumbImage .thumbTextWrap { background:#8b133c; }

When I changed that or removed it changed the background hover color as needed in the dev tools.